# Mysql SELECT LIKE all combination of a string

Tags: mysql, database, select, regexp-replace

I have a table with products:

```
**ID > Product**
01 > Cable Printer Black USB
02 > Power Cable for PC
03 > Headset with microphone USB blue
04 > USB Extension Cable
```

I need do a search like:
USB + Cable
and the result shows USB+Cable in any sequence: (usb+cable or cable+usb)

And the result show:

```
01 > Cable Printer Black USB
04 > USB Extension Cable
```

I tried with REGEXP, but it shows any register with the 2 terms, but I need ALL terms in the result, not ANY.

```
SELECT * FROM tbproducts WHERE product REGEXP 'USB|Cable'
```

Show:

```
01 > Cable Printer Black USB
02 > Power Cable for PC
03 > Headset with microphone USB blue
04 > USB Extension Cable
```

Comment: I suggest you read about [FULLTEXT indexing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: REGEXP cannot use an index. You could do this with two REGEXP clauses, or a more complicated REGEXP, but it will do a full table scan. FULLTEXT index in BOOLEAN mode is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You will be more happy, using a [Full TEX INDEX][1],

But you can do following

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbproducts (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `Product` VARCHAR(32),
>     FULLTEXT (`Product`)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO tbproducts
>   (`ID`, `Product`)
> VALUES
>   ('01', 'Cable Printer Black USB'),
>   ('02', 'Power Cable for PC'),
>   ('03', 'Headset with microphone USB blue'),
>   ('04', 'USB Extension Cable');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbproducts WHERE Product REGEXP '(USB.*Cable|Cable.*USB)'
> ```

> ```
> ID | Product                
> -: | :----------------------
>  1 | Cable Printer Black USB
>  4 | USB Extension Cable
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbproducts t1
> WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbproducts t2 WHERE Product LIKE '%USB%' AND t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`)
> AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbproducts t2 WHERE Product LIKE '%Cable%'AND t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`)
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Product                
> -: | :----------------------
>  1 | Cable Printer Black USB
>  4 | USB Extension Cable
> ```

## Update add full TEXT search for completeness

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbproducts WHERE MATCH (Product) AGAINST ('+USB +Cable' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Product                
> -: | :----------------------
>  1 | Cable Printer Black USB
>  4 | USB Extension Cable
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=531767e79b4958dc39a22f1319db3466)*

Comment: Nice, in PHP I can do a explode with the search term and create a literal query with the second option. Using REGEXP will be a problem if I have more then 2 word, because I need recreate all possible combination, but with "EXISTS" I need only repeat the last part of query. I will try and post the result. Thanks.

Comment: i added the full text search , so that you can see how it works